# Adding ViewController for MainWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

*I am new to iOS programming, just to warn you!*

I'm using Xcode 4.2 to build a simple app. I have followed this [Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sROdA4w4x9Y&noredirect=1) to create a MainWindow.xib after creating and empty application.

I want to show a scrollView where I can scroll horizontally between 2 pages (which I have done in tutorials, and therefore not worried about).

What I do need help with is this: as far as I understand,  I would need to do the logic for my MainWindow.xib in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

I want to know how to abstract the code into another viewController. I would also like to know if this is the correct method to handle the logic, or if I'm misunderstanding something here (most likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a particularly easy to follow document by Apple about adding a view controller to the main window.  [Read it here!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html)

Comment: Additonal:  This article shows you a number of different ways you can achieve the same result, with and without NIB files.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before, and just did again. The app crashes saying that my new nib was loaded but the view outlet was not set. In my new nib, I checked the Identity Inspector of the view, which is pointing to File's Owner. And the File's Owner's class is set to the correct UIViewController. Any ideas?

Comment: For clarification. I have MainWindow.xib (with just a window in it), A UIViewController class (That I'm trying to set as rootViewController), and a corresponding xib for the controller (with a view in it). Hope that makes it a bit clearer where I am

Comment: I suggest playing around with the various new project templates to see what each one does, and how they work.

Comment: Sorry for the comment barrage, but I've fixed it. I had created an IB Outlet and had connected that to the file's owner instead of the actual view in IB.